# If fancybox has Error

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Fancybox adds the class of the type to the `fancybox-wrap` div.

Like, when it's an image, it gets `fancybox-type-image`

I'd like to add the error class too, when there's an error (ie. the image doesn't load), so it gets the class `fancybox-type-error`.

**Why?**
My images have titles. When an image fails to load, I don't want to show a title. That's why I need to give the upper parent div the fancybox-type-error class, so I can target the title and hide it. Check tinyurl.com/qjm2724 for more clarification. Click the last Eiffel Tower image. I need that title gone! :p

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `tpl` API option to add your custom *class* to the fancybox html structure. In the case of the error message you could do :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    tpl: {
        error: '<p class="fancybox-error myClass">I want to display a different error meesage here.</p>'
    }
});
```

**Notice** that I also added `myClass` to the `<p>` element, apart from changing the error message's content.

Then you can use regular css rules to style your error message like

```
.myClass {
    color: #f80000;
    background-color: #00bbbb;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tDWpK/)**

Comment: I have done that already, indeed. But I have to target the parent div. All my images have titles. But when an image fails to load, I want to hide the title. I  can only do that if the parent div has a fancybox-type-error class for example. For more clarification, see http://tinyurl.com/qjm2724 and check the last Eiffel Tower, I want to hide that title.